# Expected value of a dice Game with 18 rolls at most - land on a 6 to lose it all, anything else wins you the dice value

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, dice

I've been given a question with a game:
''
You accumulate points. you start with a point value of 0, and you roll the die at most 18 times. every time you roll the die you win as much points the number shown, unless you rolled a 6 in which case you lose it all and the game ends. what's the expected number of points at the end of the game?
''
I'm honestly quite stumped - I tried reasoning as follows:
X = dice i's result, W = total wins. **my attempt:**
$$E( \text{pts in turn i} | X_i \neq 6) = \frac{1+2+3+4+5}{6} = \frac{15}{6}$$
We can at most play 18 turns, and the dice rolls are independent. We can compute E to be:
$$E[W| U_{i=1}^{18} X_i \neq 6] = 18 \cdot \frac{15}{6} $$
$$E[W] = E[W| U_{i=1}^{18} X_i \neq 6]P( U_{i=1}^{18} X_i \neq 6) +  E[W| (U_{i=1}^{18} X_i \neq 6)^C]P(( U_{i=1}^18 X_i \neq 6)^C)$$
so that should equal $$E[W] = 18 \cdot \frac{15}{6} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{18}$$
which isn't the case - I'm unsure as to whether my formula is correct (couldn't find it) or if I'm thinking about this problem properly.

Comment: The problem doesn't make sense unless you specify what strategy you are following.  Presumably the goal is something like "describe the strategy that has the highest expected payout" or something like that.

Comment: I think the strategy is just to roll until the game ends either via 18 rolls or by losing

Comment: That seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: If there is no strategy, and you just keep rolling until a "6" or until 18 rolls, then I think that $$18 \times \frac{15}{6} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{18}$$ is correct.  If you are sure that that answer is incorrect, is it possible that you have misinterpreted the problem, and that the problem composer allows you to quit *prematurely*, keeping your winnings?  What is the **official answer**?

Comment: Yeah- the expectation should be pretty low i think

Comment: What is the **official answer**?

Comment: I have no official answer but I can submit any guess I want an unlimited number of times,

Comment: the exact phrasing out of google translate: "In a dice game, you start with a zero sum, and throw the dice a maximum of 18 times. In each toss, you win the amount shown on the die, unless the number 6 comes out, then you lose everything and the game ends.

What is the winning expectancy at the end of the game?"

Comment: Thank you! What's the formula this is based off of? I'll ask around and report back regards that question and the authors intent

Comment: My prior comment was incorrect (and is now deleted).  Here, you have to compute the probability that you never throw a $6$ and then multiply that by the expected value, given that you only throw $1, \cdots, 5$.

Comment: If you're allowed to quit prematurely, it seems like this could be solved using dynamic programming. Your decision to stop should only depend on your current total and how many rolls you have left.

Comment: Looks correct to me! Nice job.

Comment: The wording "a maximum of 18 times" is unambiguous: it obviously means that you can stop at any time and take your winnings with you. Otherwise it would just say "18 times", wouldn't it? So your formula is wrong.

Comment: You will roll at most 18 times, but of course you might stop early with a 6. I think that is what is meant.

Comment: @TonyK I disagree.  The wording "a maximum of 18 times" could represent that you keep rolling until you get a $~6,~$ or until you have rolled $~18~$ times.  So, the wording does not preclude the interpretation that you are **not allowed** to voluntarily stop rolling, before rolling $~18~$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You roll 18 times (just continue after a six, even though you lost). The probability of no six is $(5/6)^{18}$. If there is no six the expected number of eyes is three per roll, or 54 in all 18 rounds. Your expected winnings are

$54 \cdot (5/6)^{18}$ ≈ 2.028

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a small mistake in your answer! This problem can be couched within the probability space $\{(1,...,6)^{18}\}$ equipped with uniform measure, so that each outcome has probability $1/6^{18}$. We aim to calculate the expected value of the random variable
$$
f(x_1,...,x_{18}) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^{18}x_j\right) {1}\{{x_1\ne 6,...,x_{18}\ne 6}\}
$$

The expected value of $f$ is
$$
\sum_{i_1=1}^5 \cdots \sum_{i_{18}=1}^5 \frac{i_1+\cdots + i_{18}}{6^{18}}= \frac{5^{17}\times 15\times 18}{6^{18}} = (5/6)^{17} \times 18 \times \frac{15}{6}. 
$$
I have confirmed via simulation that this appears correct.

I believe the problem with your calculation is that you need to calculate the conditional mean of the die roll given that the roll is not a 6. This is not equal to 15/6 as in your calculation.

Comment: i think your f is the sum of all the winnings given that no dice roll comes up to be 6, finding the expected value of f shouldn’t be the same as that of the entire game I think. I’m having trouble understanding your second line.

Comment: You got it right btw!

Comment: Cool! Yeah notice in the sum that the indices only range over 1,…,5. Actually this leads to the same calculation as @gnasher, and explains the nuts and bolts of why it is true.